# Как повернуть объект в PyQT5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Кто нибудь знает как повернуть QWidget или любой другой объект в pyqt5?
Все что я нашел это примеры на C и код написаный на [pyqt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339685/how-to-rotate-a-qpushbutton)
Я не знаю почему но в pyqt4 все виджеты почемуто привязаны к QtGui.
Я пытался адаптировать код к pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)

class RotatedButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent, orientation = "west"):
        super(RotatedButton,self).__init__(text, parent)
        self.orientation = orientation

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QStylePainter(self)
        painter.rotate(90)
        painter.translate(0, -1 * self.width());
        painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, self.getSyleOptions())

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        size = super(RotatedButton, self).minimumSizeHint()
        size.transpose()
        return size

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = super(RotatedButton, self).sizeHint()
        size.transpose()
        return size

    def getSyleOptions(self):
        options = QStyleOptionButton()
        options.initFrom(self)
        size = options.rect.size()
        size.transpose()
        options.rect.setSize(size)
        options.features =  QStyleOptionButton.None
        if self.isFlat():
            options.features |=  QStyleOptionButton.Flat
        if self.menu():
            options.features |=  QStyleOptionButton.HasMenu
        if self.autoDefault() or self.isDefault():
            options.features |= QStyleOptionButton.AutoDefaultButton
        if self.isDefault():
            options.features |=  QStyleOptionButton.DefaultButton
        if self.isDown() or (self.menu() and self.menu().isVisible()):
            options.state |=  QStyle.State_Sunken
        if self.isChecked():
            options.state |=  QStyle.State_On
        if not self.isFlat() and not self.isDown():
            options.state |=  QStyle.State_Raised

        options.text = self.text()
        options.icon = self.icon()
        options.iconSize = self.iconSize()
        return options







class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.attr_layout)

        self.rb0 = RotatedButton("Hello", self, orientation="west")                             #QRadioButton() # 'rb0'

        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb0)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 400))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

но возникла проблемма в QStyleOptionButton.None. Эта строка выдает синтаксическую ошибку и как код впринципе запускался после нее я не знаю.

Мне нужно просто повернуть QWidget чтобы понять как это работает.

Comment: В `Qt4` все виджеты были в модуле `QtGui`, а переход к `Qt5` внес разделение на `QtGui` и `QtWidgets`. Мне кажется что то, что вы делаете лучше делать через графическую сцену: QGraphicsScene. В нее можно и полноценные виджеты добавлять

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, лучше попробовать через [QGraphicsScene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) реализовывать:

- Метод [QGraphicsScene::addWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget) позволит добавлять на сцену виджеты, оборачивая их в [QGraphicsProxyWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsproxywidget.html)
- Для поворота виджета использовался метод [QGraphicsItem::setRotation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation)

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6935975018d960db293319329d24c4cdb88f430a/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/RotatedButton__QGraphicsScene.py#L20)

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGraphicsScene, \
    QGraphicsView, QGraphicsLinearLayout, QGraphicsWidget, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 200, 200)

        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.view.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        scene_layout = QGraphicsLinearLayout(Qt.Horizontal)

        form = QGraphicsWidget()
        form.setLayout(scene_layout)

        self.scene.addItem(form)

        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        self.rb0 = QPushButton("Hello")
        proxy_rb0 = self.scene.addWidget(self.rb0)
        scene_layout.addItem(proxy_rb0)

        self.rb1 = QPushButton("Hello")
        proxy_rb1 = self.scene.addWidget(self.rb1)
        proxy_rb1.setRotation(90)
        scene_layout.addItem(proxy_rb1)

        self.rb2 = QPushButton("Hello")
        proxy_rb2 = self.scene.addWidget(self.rb2)
        proxy_rb2.setRotation(180)
        scene_layout.addItem(proxy_rb2)

        self.rb3 = QPushButton("Hello")
        proxy_rb3 = self.scene.addWidget(self.rb3)
        proxy_rb3.setRotation(-166)
        scene_layout.addItem(proxy_rb3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Window()
    w.setMinimumSize(0, 200)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно ли убрать полосы прокрутки и одступы?

Comment: Можно, гуглите про QGraphicsView, я с ним почти не работал, поэтому сразу не скажу :)

Comment: Навсякий случай спрошу. Вы не знаете почему кнопка находится либо в центре либо улетает кудато в сторону если повернута на 90 градусов.  И что именно отвечает за одступы внутри белого квадрата. Я удалил все кнопки кроме одной.

Comment: @orlatym, это сцена, т.е. область с объектами и ее нужно настраивать, чтобы объекты создавались не относительно центра (по моему, это я сделал указав setSceneRect, возможно нужно еще и QGraphicsView указывать setSceneRect) и чтобы "камера" представления (QGraphicsView) показывала так, чтобы отступов не было. А так, попробуйте: `self.view.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignLeft)`

Comment: Ну у меня в сцене ничего не поменялось [Ваш код](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvto9.png) [Код с одной кнопкой и без layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH9c8.png)

Comment: @orlatym, методом перебора нашел: `scene_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` :)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QWidget, QStylePainter, QSizePolicy, 
    QStyleOptionButton, QStyle, QHBoxLayout, QButtonGroup, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)


class RotatedButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Maximum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)   
        self.setFixedWidth(2*self.fontMetrics().height())

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QStylePainter(self)
        painter.rotate(-90)                                               
        painter.translate(-self.height(), 0)
        option = QStyleOptionButton()
        self.initStyleOption(option)
        size = option.rect.size()
        size.transpose()
        option.rect.setSize(size)
        painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, option)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.attr_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.attr_layout)

#        self.rb0 = RotatedButton("Hello World", self, orientation="west")      
        self.rb0 = RotatedButton("Hello World", self)

        self.attr_layout.addWidget(self.rb0)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.rb0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 400))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]